# kotlin sealed class list items returning null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-multiplatform

I really didn't know what the title should be

I manage navigation in a compose multiplatform application with precompose, and all screens are listed as subclasses of a sealed class. In order to form the bottom navigation, i have created a list as part of the companion object to the Screen sealed class

iterating through this list results in the value being used as the current route returning null

```kotlin
// screens.kt


sealed class Screens(val route: String) {
    sealed class MainNavigation(route: String, val icon: ImageVector, val label: String) : Screens(route) {
        data object Challenges : MainNavigation("challenges", Icons.Default.EventNote, "Challenges")

        data object Feed : MainNavigation("home", Icons.Default.Home, "Feed")


    }

    companion object {
        val navScreens: List<MainNavigation> = listOf(
            MainNavigation.Feed,
            MainNavigation.Challenges,
            MainNavigation.Leaderboard,
            MainNavigation.Profile
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
// navigation.kt
NavHost(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()),
            navigator = navigator,
            navTransition = NavTransition(),
            initialRoute = if (state.value.authState == AuthState.Authenticated) Screens.MainNavigation.Profile.route else Screens.Onboarding.Landing.route
        )
```

```kotlin
// somewhere in navigation.kt
Screens.navScreens.forEach { screen ->
                            println("screen $screen")
                        }
```

All the routes would be printed out except for the route that forms the initialRoute in the `navhost`

Comment: Make sure the initialization order is correct, add println to both places and see which prints first

Comment: thank you @gavr, reminded me to post my solution

Answer (score 0):

Due to [KT-8970](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-8970/Object-is-uninitialized-null-when-accessed-from-static-context-ex.-companion-object-with-initialization-loop), i had to use a workaround.

```
private object Initializer {
        val navScreens: List<MainNavigation> = listOf(
            MainNavigation.Feed,
            MainNavigation.Challenges,
            MainNavigation.Leaderboard,
            MainNavigation.Profile,
        )
    }

    companion object {
        val navScreens: List<MainNavigation>
            get() = Initializer.navScreens
    }
```